# C# how to access cells after vertical merge in word table?

Tags: c#, ms-word

The c# code created a very long table in MS-word file. Then two cells in one column are being merge (1,5) (2,5).
If I try to merge two more cells in same column e.g. (5,5), (6,5) - I get the following error: "Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells"

The real target is to merge several group of cells in the same column, and in other columns.

How can I merge several groups of cells in same column?

The code used to create the table and merge:

```
            for (int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            {
                genTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Range.Text = (100 + i).ToString();
                genTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].Range.Text = (200 + i).ToString();
                genTable.Rows[i].Cells[3].Range.Text = (300 + i).ToString();
                genTable.Rows[i].Cells[4].Range.Text = (400 + i).ToString();
                genTable.Rows[i].Cells[5].Range.Text = (500 + i).ToString();

            }

            genTable.Rows[1].Cells[5].Merge(genTable.Rows[2].Cells[5]);

            genTable.Rows[5].Cells[5].Merge(genTable.Rows[6].Cells[5]);
```

Comment: Once cells are merged rows and/or columns can't be accessed via their collections - a table must be "well-formed" in order to use these collections. The only possibility is to use the `Table.Cell` method to pick up single cells. You'll need to do quite a bit of testing / experimentation to figure out how to best use it to get the required combinations. I'd probably try working from the end of the table to the beginning...

Comment: Can you try going bottom up? Not sure if that will work but might be worth a try. Merge rows 5 and 6 first, then rows 1 and 2.

Comment: The bottom up way doesn't work :(

Comment: Would it be easier if the merge is done while creating the table? The table is created using same c# code.

Comment: Perhaps I could insert using the C# code, a VBA macro to execute the merge cells task? And then run it?

Comment: Dont't try to merge cells. use nested tables instead.

Comment: It makes no difference when the cells are merged, unless they're merged **after** the code in the question is executed. VBA has the same limiations as C# in regard to working with merged cells.